# Executing PL/SQL Begin/End procedure from Oracle JDBC thin driver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, ora-00933

I am trying to create Oracle PL/SQL procedures and execute them via Oracle JDBC (thin driver).  Here is the full PL/SQL script:

```
begin
for i in (select owner, constraint_name, table_name from all_constraints where owner = 'SCHEMA' and status = 'ENABLED') LOOP
execute immediate 'alter table SCHEMA.'||i.table_name||' disable constraint SCHEMA.'||i.constraint_name||'';
end loop;
end;
/
begin
for i in (select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'SCHEMA') LOOP
execute immediate 'truncate table SCHEMA.'||i.table_name||'';
end loop;
end;
/
begin
for i in (select owner, constraint_name, table_name from all_constraints where owner = 'SCHEMA' and status = 'DISABLED') LOOP
execute immediate 'alter table SCHEMA.'||i.table_name||' enable constraint SCHEMA.'||i.constraint_name||'';
end loop;
end;
/
```

In java I am splitting on '/' so each begin end block is executed in a separate statement.  The java code to execute the statement is:

```
CallableStatement c = dbc.getConnection().prepareCall(sqlStatement);
c.executeUpdate();
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

How do I format this and execute the PL/SQL in JDBC?

**Updated:** To clarify, all three statements are executed without the '/' delimiter that is split on.

**Updated:** The oracle server is the following version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I don't see any problem with the posted code. Just make sure that your SQL statement ends with a semicolon. So the semicolon is required, the slash must not be present.

Comment: Check Codo's comment: "the slash must not be present" is the key phrase.

Comment: I have updated the question to indicate that the '/' is indeed not present when I execute the update on the CallableStatement.

Comment: @Codo The Sql statement shouldn't ends with a semicolon. This is a common error in a dynamic sql string. 
A SQL statement does not need a terminator character, maybe you're confusing with a SQL*PLus SQL TERMINATOR environment variable!

Comment: @zep: It's a PL/SQL BEGIN/END block. It might work without the semicolon (I haven't tried that), but it certainly works with it. I agree that for DML statements, it would be a mistake.

Comment: @Codo No, it's isn't a dynamic PL/SQL BLOCK. Tonysbd wants only a dynamic sql statement in the execute immediate clause. It's only a single dynamic sql statement for each loop.
If it were a "Dynamic PL/SQL Block", you could be right. In that case, the entire block should be a valid PL/SQL block.

Comment: @zep: My understanding is that tonysbd executes "begin for i in ... end loop; end;" And that's certainly a PL/SQL block.

Comment: @tonysbd: I've read zep's answer and agree with him that the ALTER TABLE command should be fixed. Could it be that you have never executed the script you posted at the beginning of your question?

Comment: @Codo Sure, and he included correctly all the semicolons in that PL/SQL block. I've just contested your affirmation :"Just make sure that your SQL statement ends with a semicolon."-> It's isn't true.
-- dynamic sql in the example = 1 dynamic statement( not a PL/sql block) -->> No semicolon
-- the execute immediate is included in a PL/SQL block = pl/SQL statement-->> Yes semicolon(no at the end of a single SQL statement withing the dynamic string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "enable /diable" constraint you shouldn't add the schema name (your'SCHEMA).

From the manual:
[ALTER TABLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_3001.htm#i2054940)

Your example:

```
begin
    for i in (select owner, constraint_name, table_name
              from   all_constraints
              where  owner = 'SCHEMA'
              and    status = 'ENABLED')
    loop
        execute immediate 'alter table SCHEMA.' || i.table_name ||
                          ' disable constraint ' || i.constraint_name;
    end loop;
end;
```

Test Query

```
select ac.constraint_name, ac.table_name, ac.status, ac.owner
from   all_constraints ac
where  ac.owner = 'HR'
and    ac.constraint_name = 'EMP_SALARY_MIN'
```

Result

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                TABLE_NAME                     STATUS   OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMP_SALARY_MIN                 EMPLOYEES                      ENABLED  HR
```

Correct dynamic sql

```
begin
    execute immediate 'alter table HR.EMPLOYEES disable constraint EMP_SALARY_MIN';
end;
```

Previous query result

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                TABLE_NAME                     STATUS   OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMP_SALARY_MIN                 EMPLOYEES                      DISABLED HR
```

Comment: I recognized this as an issue after reading up on oracle constraints.  After the SQL was corrected per zep's answer I still got the error.  Turns out my current user required the "Create Any Index" and "Drop Any Index" privileges in order to successfully disable/enable foreign and primary keys.  Awarding answer to zep.